# How to search by product price Woocommerce WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce, price

I am developing a website from scratch. For the store I am using Woocommerce.

With default WordPress search I can see the products been searched displaying. But I can't see any product when I enter the price. How can I use WordPress default search to show the product search by price?

My search code

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url('/') ?>">
<div class="rw-wrapper">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="s" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" placeholder="Search for...">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
</span>
</div><!-- /input-group -->
</div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
</div>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @Dodge I am using WordPress default search and code been updated. It is better if I can get any direction to move forward. Hope you're clear with my requirement.